# How to add print option to print the content of a link in grails using JQuery

Tags: jquery, grails

I am working in a web application using Grails. I can generate report and download the report. But while I am trying to add print option to print the PDF, it does not work.

My Controller code :

```
def generateVoucherReport() {
    String id = params?.id;
    def jasperDTOList = salesOrderVoucherInfo(id);
    chain(controller:'jasper', action:'index', model:[data:jasperDTOList], params:params)
    return false
}
```

My GSP code :

```
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <a class="vReport PDF"><img src="${resource(dir: 'images/jasper', file:'PDF.gif')}" alt="Grails"/></a>                    
</div>
```

And My JQuery code :

```
$(".PDF").click(function() {
    var reporturl = '${createLink(action: 'generateVoucherReport')}'
    document.body.innerHTML =
       "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" +
       $("a.vReport").attr("href", reporturl+ "?id=" + $('#id').val() + "&_format=" +
       "PDF" + "&_name=salesOrderVoucher&_file=salesOrderVoucher") + "</body>";
    window.print();    
});
```